# Can I gather multiple variables from text boxes in a quicker fashion?

Tags: javascript, pseudocode, code.org

In code.org, I'm trying to gather data from text boxes where they can enter numbers. I want to assign the numbers entered into the text boxes into different variables.

Right now, I am individually grabbing each variable by itself.

I am currently creating variables at the beginning of my code like this.

```
var player1 = "player1";
var player2 = "player2";
var player3 = "player3";
var player4 = "player4";
var player5 = "player5";
```

Then after I used the onEvent handler function, I grab each of the numbers individually using the getText function.

```
onEvent("team2Button", "click", function () {
  player1 = getText("player1");
  player2 = getText("player2");
  player3 = getText("player3");
  player4 = getText("player4");
  player5 = getText("player5");
});
```

Since I have many around 30 sets of data to collect, is there a quicker way to assign these values into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Object:

```
const players = {};

for(let i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
 players[`player${i}`] = `player${i}`
}

onEvent('button', 'click', function(){
   for(let key in players){
     players[key] = getText(key)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "design" tab to create a text input, and then write some code to add a new entry to a list every time you type something in and press enter:

```
var players = [];
onEvent("text_input1", "change", function(event) {
  var name = getText("text_input1");
  appendItem(players, name);
  setText("text_input1", '');
  console.log("added player: " + name);
});
```

If you want to keep this text input separate from the rest of your app, you could put it on a different screen. For example: https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/3vINC-jX6LHkiARJCoCmUQ